# UITableviewController header view constraints?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, interface-builder

I am using a UITableviewController and I know dragging a UIView on top of the table view makes this the header view. I can specify the dimensions for it but I can't add any constraints. I want to add a height constraint but is not possible. When I tap the align or pin button in Xcode the options are all greyed out. How do you specify constraints on a header view in a UITableviewController.

Comment: You can just set the height in the size inspector.

Comment: It is a header view with dynamic height. It will change hence I need the constraint. When I change the height the table view below the header view does not update.  Ie. Header view height is 130 and when I change the height at run time to 50. There is 80 space between the header view and the start of the table view.

Comment: Inside the header view I have buttons and labels which all have auto layout constraints.  Are you saying:
let tempHeaderView = tableView.headerView
tableView.headerView = nil
//adjust tempHeaderView
tableView.headerView = tempHeaderView?

Comment: `self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(x:0.0,y: 0.0, width:self.tableView.frame.size.width,height: 50.0)` will work fine.

Comment: That works in the viewdidload. It doesn't work in the viewwillappear. As my headerView will need to be updated each time it appears. Any ideas? I've tried headerview needsLayout and tableview needslayout but no dice. There is still a gap from the bottom of header and start of tableview.

Comment: You should post more code, because in the sample project I created I can place that line in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear or in a method that is called after a delay, and it worked in each case.